# Can I filter artifact download?

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a single build that creates one artifact for each target environment (i.e. CI, QA, Prod).

Currently, my release is downloading EVERY artifact for each environment. Is it possible for my release to QA (for example) to only pull the QA artifact?

Comment: Building per-environment is a bad practice. You should build one set of artifacts and then deploy that set of artifacts through your environment pipeline.

Comment: There is a Download Artifacts extension, you can try and check the result. (I updated my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with this extension: [Download Artifacts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chamindac.chamindac-vsts-release-task-download-artifacts)